# Cálculo com virgula em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou refazendo um sistema de Aferição Agrícola e estou encontrando uma dificuldade para realizar alguns cálculos, inicialmente preparei os `input´s` para receberem somente `números`, em seguida formatei os mesmos para receberem uma `vírgula` e uma casa decimal ao receberem valores, até ai tudo funciona.
Ao tentar realizar um soma e depois a média uma das minhas função está acusando erro.
Vou tentar não complicar postando o código comentado.

Esse é o meu formulário:

```html
<div class="row">
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal1" id="deterVal1" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal2" id="deterVal2" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal3" id="deterVal3" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal4" id="deterVal4" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal5" id="deterVal5" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
   <section class="col col-2">
      <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="MediaFinal" id="MediaFinal" value="" class="form-control " onfocus="calMediaAfericao(this)" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onKeyUp="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
      </label>
   </section>
</div>
```

Função para permitir somente números:

```js
function SomenteNumeros(input) {
 if ((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57))
  event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Inserir a vírgula e uma casa decimal

```js
function FormataValor(campo, tammax, teclapres) {

 var tecla = teclapres.keyCode;
 var vr = campo.value;
 vr = vr.replace("/", "");
 vr = vr.replace("/", "");
 vr = vr.replace(",", "");
 vr = vr.replace(".", "");
 vr = vr.replace(".", "");
 vr = vr.replace(".", "");
 vr = vr.replace(".", "");
 tam = vr.length;

 if (tam < tammax && tecla != 8) {
  tam = vr.length + 1;
 }

 if (tecla == 8) {
  tam = tam - 1;
 }

 if (tecla == 8 || (tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) || (tecla >= 96 && tecla <= 105)) {
  if (tam <= 1) {
   campo.value = vr;
  }
  tam = tam - 1;
  if ((tam > 1) && (tam <= 5)) {
   campo.value = vr.substr(0, tam - 1) + ',' + vr.substr(tam - 1, tam);
  }

  if ((tam > 5) && (tam <= 8)) {
   campo.value = vr.substr(0, tam - 1) + ',' + vr.substr(tam - 1, tam);
  }
 }
}
```

Antes de fazer a soma e calcular a média chamo uma função que substitui a vírgula por ponto, essa função está acusando uma falha, o que tento fazer é isso:

```js
function calMediaAfericao() {

 var vlrDet1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('deterVal1').value, 10);
 var vlrDet2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('deterVal2').value, 10);
 var vlrDet3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('deterVal3').value, 10);
 var vlrDet4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('deterVal4').value, 10);
 var vlrDet5 = parseInt(document.getElementById('deterVal5').value, 10);

 vlrDet1 = Number(substituiVirgula(vlrDet1));
 vlrDet2 = Number(substituiVirgula(vlrDet1));
 vlrDet3 = Number(substituiVirgula(vlrDet1));
 vlrDet4 = Number(substituiVirgula(vlrDet1));
 vlrDet5 = Number(substituiVirgula(vlrDet1));

 document.getElementById('MediaFinal').value = (vlrDet1 + vlrDet2 + vlrDet3 + vlrDet4 + vlrDet5) / 5;

}
```

A função `substituiVirgula` e a que está acusando erro, como pode ser visto aqui:

```html
VM11866:284 Uncaught TypeError: valor.indexOf is not a function
    at substituiVirgula (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:284:13)
    at calMediaAfericao (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:338:20)
    at HTMLInputElement.onfocus (VM11873 iAfericaoAgricola-novo.php:1)
```

A função é essa:

```js
 function substituiVirgula(valor){
  if (valor.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
   var novoValor = valor.replace(",",".");
   return novoValor;
  } else {
   return valor;
  }    
 }
```

Comment: O problema é que tem algum valor que não é uma `String`. Antes da linha `if (valor.indexOf(",") >= 0) {` coloque um `valor = valor.toString();`

Comment: Talvez você queira usar uma biblioteca para formatação de números, como o [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) - isso evitaria muita dor de cabeça. Além disso A sua função de formatação tem repetições e o código para permitir somente números é facilmente burlável.

Comment: @adventistapr, uma dica, inserir vários trechos de código executável não ajuda a simular nada da sua dúvida, pois os trechos são executados isoladamente. Na próxima vez coloque tudo em apenas um trecho de código, como fiz na minha resposta abaixo.

Comment: Olá @Marco, foi na preocupação de não faltar argumentos para o bom entendimento, mas agradeço a dica.

Comment: @adventistapr Sim, eu até entendi isso, justamente por isso não editei sua pergunta, mas não é possível executar sem que nós coloquemos em local único.

Comment: Se possível aproveita a dica do @Renan e tente utilizar o Inputmask, já que eu vi que você utiliza jQuery, vai facilitar e aperfeiçoar bastante a validação dos campos.

Comment: Agradeço @Marco, já estou alterando nesse momento, valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi um conjunto de pequenos erros, mas o principal é que a função `calMediaAfericao()` que era chamado no `onfocus` do último campo é quem acabava retornando o erro `valor.indexOf is not a function` pois você convertia os valores utilizando `parseInt` *(que deveria ser `parseFloat` já que é um valor decimal)* e passava pra função `substituiVirgula` um valor de tipo numérico, onde não existe o método `indexOf`.

Tenho algumas ressalvas quanto a maneira que você escolheu para chamar o método de cálculo, pois creio que um botão para isso fosse mais interessante funcionalmente, porém alterando apenas para ficar funcional para o seu objetivo, ficaria assim:

```js
function SomenteNumeros(input) {
  if ((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57))
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function FormataValor(campo, tammax, teclapres) {
  var tecla = teclapres.keyCode;
  var vr = campo.value;
  vr = vr.replace("/", "");
  vr = vr.replace("/", "");
  vr = vr.replace(",", "");
  vr = vr.replace(".", "");
  vr = vr.replace(".", "");
  vr = vr.replace(".", "");
  vr = vr.replace(".", "");
  tam = vr.length;

  if (tam < tammax && tecla != 8) {
    tam = vr.length + 1;
  }

  if (tecla == 8) {
    tam = tam - 1;
  }

  if (tecla == 8 || (tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) || (tecla >= 96 && tecla <= 105)) {
    if (tam <= 1) {
      campo.value = vr;
    }
    tam = tam - 1;
    if ((tam > 1) && (tam <= 5)) {
      campo.value = vr.substr(0, tam - 1) + ',' + vr.substr(tam - 1, tam);
    }

    if ((tam > 5) && (tam <= 8)) {
      campo.value = vr.substr(0, tam - 1) + ',' + vr.substr(tam - 1, tam);
    }
  }
}

function calMediaAfericao(campo) {
  var vlrDet1 = parseFloat(substituiVirgula(document.getElementById('deterVal1').value), 10);
  var vlrDet2 = parseFloat(substituiVirgula(document.getElementById('deterVal2').value), 10);
  var vlrDet3 = parseFloat(substituiVirgula(document.getElementById('deterVal3').value), 10);
  var vlrDet4 = parseFloat(substituiVirgula(document.getElementById('deterVal4').value), 10);
  var vlrDet5 = parseFloat(substituiVirgula(document.getElementById('deterVal5').value), 10);

  campo.value = (vlrDet1 + vlrDet2 + vlrDet3 + vlrDet4 + vlrDet5) / 5;
}

function substituiVirgula(valor) {
  if (valor.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
    var novoValor = valor.replace(",", ".");
    return novoValor;
  } else {
    return valor;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal1" id="deterVal1" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onkeyup="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
    </label>
  </section>
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal2" id="deterVal2" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onkeyup="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
    </label>
  </section>
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal3" id="deterVal3" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onkeyup="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
    </label>
  </section>
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal4" id="deterVal4" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onkeyup="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
    </label>
  </section>
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="deterVal5" id="deterVal5" value="" class="form-control" onKeyPress="SomenteNumeros(this)" onkeyup="FormataValor(this,5,event)">
    </label>
  </section>
  <section class="col col-2">
    <label class="input">
      <input type="text" name="MediaFinal" id="MediaFinal" value="" class="form-control " onfocus="calMediaAfericao(this)" readonly />
    </label>
  </section>
</div>
```